# Angular-save-html-to-pdf with ng-show

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf

I've an angular app where I have to generate a PDF from an HTML element.

I'm using the angular module [ng-html-to-pdf-save](https://github.com/hearsid/ng-html-to-pdf-save).

Standardly, it works perfectly, but I want to hide the exported HTML div, the user doesn't need to see it.

I put a `ng-show='false'` on the div, but then the exported PDF is completely blank...

My export button :

```
<button pdf-save-button="exportHV" pdf-name="exportHV.pdf" title="Export" 
        class="btn btn-primary pull-right ">
  <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> Export
</button></h1>
```

My exported div :

```
<div pdf-save-content="exportHV" ng-show="true">
    A TEST !
</div>
```

With `ng-show="true"`, the generated PDF contain "A TEST !", with `ng-show="false"`, it's blank...

Is there a working solution for exporting an hidden HTML tag ? Didn't find any solution

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please provide a link to your code working as described in a https://plnkr.co or https://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

`html-to-pdf-save` likely cannot do what you are asking for - I assume you mean you want an html element to print but not appear to the user. I'm looking into a similar issue myself, try using `angular-print` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-print), if you are still looking for an answer. It has a "print-only" section that may interest you. You should be able to select PDF as an option during printing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Ended up Just offsetting the container div -10000 and it works as expected. A little hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The div inwhich you are trying to use ng-show=true, Use css to hide this div. Use display:none;